# Ajax code doesn't work inside of jquery form validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I want to write (register section)  code that can check if email have been used in past or the login is empty.

The code is working fine, but my ajax code dont run at all.

I checked everything, path to php file is good, variables are good etc. Don't how to solve it.

Code:

```
$('.login').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var error = 0;
    var self = $(this);

    var $name = self.find('[type=name]');
    var $email = self.find('[type=email]');
    var $pass = self.find('[type=password]');

    var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    if (!emailRegex.test($email.val())) {
        createErrTult("Błąd! Email ma zły format!", $email)
        error++;
    }

    //MY AJAX CODE
    var email = $email.val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '../inc/rejestracja.php?action=emailcheck',
        data: {
            'email': email
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(odp) {
            if (odp == 1) {
                createErrTult("Błąd! taki email już istnieje w bazie!", $email)
                error++;
            }
        }
    });

    if ($name.val().length > 1 && $name.val() != $name.attr('placeholder')) {
        $name.removeClass('invalid_field');
    } else {
        createErrTult('Error! Wrong name!', $name)
        error++;
    }

    if ($pass.val().length > 1 && $pass.val() != $pass.attr('placeholder')) {
        $pass.removeClass('invalid_field');
    } else {
        createErrTult('Error! Wrong password!', $pass)
        error++;
    }

    if (error != 0) return;
    self.find('[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    self.children().fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).remove()
    })
    $('<p class="login__title">sign in <br><span class="login-edition">welcome to A.Movie</span></p><p class="success">You have successfully<br> signed in!</p>').appendTo(self)
        .hide().delay(300).fadeIn();

    // var formInput = self.serialize();
    // $.post(self.attr('action'),formInput, function(data){}); // end post
});
```

php:

```
<?php

include ("config.php");

  if($action == "emailcheck"){

      //sprawdzamy czy był już dodany plus
      $test = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from uzytkownicy where email='$email'"));
            if ($test > 0) {
                $dodano = 1;
                echo json_encode($dodano); 


      }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried capturing the `click` event instead of the `submit` event?

Comment: I'd suggest to: First, indent the code. Then add error hander in the ajax call to see if it fires. Also, have you debugged it in your browser? Is ajax call made with the right values etc?

Comment: @Sparky `submit` works fine, whole validation works exept ajax part.

Comment: At least you php code misses a closing `}`.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Missed it, at testing. That dont resolve the problem :)

Comment: @Sebi Added

`error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }`

but the whole AJAX code doesnt work, even the error hander.

So Ajax is not fired in script, but why and how to solve it?

Comment: What does developer console show? Any errors or warnings?

Comment: I did not say `submit` was the problem.  I asked you a question regarding a troubleshooting step you may or may not have taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try adding `error` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../inc/rejestracja.php?action=emailcheck',
    data: {
        'email': email
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(odp) {
        if (odp == 1) {
            createErrTult("Błąd! taki email już istnieje w bazie!", $email)
            error++;
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) // THOSE ROWS
    {
       alert(error);
    }
});
```

This may alert you about some occured error.

Second, you can try to use json instead of plain text:

Client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../inc/rejestracja.php?action=emailcheck',
    data: {
        'email': email
    },
    dataType: 'json', // THIS ROW
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(odp) {
        if (odp['result'] == 1) {
            createErrTult("Błąd! taki email już istnieje w bazie!", $email)
            error++;
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error)
    {
       alert(error);
    }
});
```

Server-side:

```
<?php

include ("config.php");
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    if($action == "emailcheck") {
      if(isset($_GET['email'])) {
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        //sprawdzamy czy był już dodany plus
        $test = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from uzytkownicy where email='$email'"));
        if ($test > 0) {
            $dodano = 1;
            echo (json_encode(array("result" => $dodano))); // THIS ROW
        }
      }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That error callback gives me:

[Object object] alert.

So its doesnt work, but why?

Comment: Erh, my bad. Try using this error callback instead: `function(xhr, textstatus, error) { alert(error); }`. This should display a proper error reason. I changed the answer's code, you can take a look.

Comment: Gives me: **Not found** as an alert

I tried also: `alert(JSON.stringify(error));`

Picture of result (looks like code of 404 page from my localhost): [reslut image link](http://s21.postimg.org/83mmtlh9j/Untitled_2.png)

Comment: Yeah, it means that $.ajax can't found specified url. It seems like you have trouble with that relative URL. By the way, you should understand that relative path is relative to your page and not to your script. Check your url again, maybe it is the error. If it is not, you can try to change it to absolute one for a while. I mean, instead of `../inc/...` use something like `http://mywebsite.pl/inc/...`.

Comment: Yep, that wast that :) Thank you.

One more question, I got response from database but `error++;` inside `success Ajax` doesnt work. How I can fix it?

Comment: Erh, sorry, it's hard to analyze from distance, i can't see your current code's version. Is success callback called now? I suggest you using developer's console in your browser and do `console.log(odp)` inside of your success callback to see what your code receives from server

Answer (score 0):

before everything check you **config.php** file path .. In your case **config.php** should be in the same path with **rejestracja.php** and try this.. lets start with ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../inc/rejestracja.php?action=emailcheck',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(odp) {
            if (odp == 1) {
                alert('Email exists');
            }else{
                alert('Email dosen\'t exists');
            }
        }
    });
```

then in php

```
<?php

include ("config.php");
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
   $action = $_GET['action'];
  if($action == "emailcheck"){
      if(isset($_GET['email'])){
         $email = $_GET['email'];
         //sprawdzamy czy był już dodany plus
         $test = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from uzytkownicy where email='$email'"));
            if ($test > 0) {
                $dodano = 1;
                echo ($dodano); 

        }
    }
}
?>
```

you should get alert with ('Email exists')

Comment: Still not working, didnt get any msg, even Email dosen\'t exists.

Ajax doesnt work at all in this code :/ Of course config is included.

when I run in browser: rejestracja.php?action=emailcheck?email=test@test.pl i get 1 so php file works fine.

Comment: @MichałLipa Ok last try change ../ in ajax url to ./ I mean change double dots to just one dot hope it help

Comment: Checked that, thats not a problem.